# Jquery counter not working correctly, show wrong date

Tags: jquery, intervals

I have problem with correctly couting date to closest thursday and closest friday.
Console show date to next thursday(23/04) and next friday(24/04), not to closest (16/04), (17/04) but                 console.log(date.getDay()); show correctly time to closest thursday and friday (4 and 5 days).
Interestingly, he showed well last week

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        (function($) {
            let compareDate;
            let timer;
            const nextThursday = () => {
                let date = new Date();
                date.setHours(12, 0, 0, 0)
                const daysToThursday = 7 - date.getDay() + 4;
                date.setDate(date.getDate() + daysToThursday);
                console.log(date.getDay());
                console.log(date)
                return date.getTime();
            };
            const nextFriday = () => {
                let date = new Date();
                date.setHours(12, 0, 0, 0)
                const daysToFriday = 7 - date.getDay() + 5;
                date.setDate(date.getDate() + daysToFriday);
                console.log(date)
                return date.getTime();
            };
            let countdownDate = nextThursday();
            let countDownDate2=nextFriday();
            function timeBetweenDates(toDate) {

            var now = new Date().getTime();
            var difference = countdownDate - now;
            var difference2 = countDownDate2 - now;
            if (difference <= 0) {
                countdownDate = nextThursday();
            } else {

                var seconds = Math.floor(difference / 1000);
                var minutes = Math.floor(seconds / 60);
                var hours = Math.floor(minutes / 60);
                var days = Math.floor(hours / 24);

                hours %= 24;
                minutes %= 60;
                seconds %= 60;
                $(".days-text").toggle(days > 0);
                $(".days").text(days ? days : "");
                $(".hours-text").toggle(hours > 0);
                $(".hours").text(hours ? hours : "");
                $(".minutes-text").toggle(minutes > 0)
                $(".minutes").text(minutes ? minutes : "");
                $(".seconds").text(seconds);
            }
            if (difference2 <= 0) {
                countDownDate2 = nextFriday();
            } else {

                var seconds2 = Math.floor(difference2 / 1000);
                var minutes2 = Math.floor(seconds2 / 60);
                var hours2 = Math.floor(minutes2 / 60);
                var days2 = Math.floor(hours2 / 24);

                hours2 %= 24;
                minutes2 %= 60;
                seconds2 %= 60;

                    $(".days-text2").toggle(days2 > 0);
                    $(".days2").text(days2 ? days2 : "");
                    $(".hours-text2").toggle(hours2 > 0);
                    $(".hours2").text(hours2 ? hours2 : "");
                    $(".minutes-text2").toggle(minutes2 > 0)
                    $(".minutes2").text(minutes2 ? minutes2 : "");
                    $(".seconds2").text(seconds2);



            }
        }

        $(function() {
            timer = setInterval(timeBetweenDates, 1000);
        })
    })(jQuery);
</script>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Formula would be `(dayOfWeek + 7 - currDayOfWeek) % 7`.

```
  const nextThursday = () => {
                let date = new Date();
                date.setHours(12, 0, 0, 0)              
                // const daysToThursday = 7 - date.getDay() + 4;
                const dayOfWeek = 4 // thursday
                date.setDate(date.getDate() + (7 + dayOfWeek - date.getDay() - 1) % 7 + 1);
                console.log(date)
                return date.getTime();
            };
            const nextFriday = () => {
                let date = new Date();
                date.setHours(12, 0, 0, 0)
                //const daysToFriday = 7 - date.getDay() + 5;
                const dayOfWeek = 5// friday
                date.setDate(date.getDate() + (7 + dayOfWeek - date.getDay() - 1) % 7 + 1);
                console.log(date)
                return date.getTime();
            };
```

Read more on this link : https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/33527/find-next-occurring-friday-or-any-dayofweek

Hope this helps.